# Create New Geofence When App Closed

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, gps, location

I'm doing research for an app I'm attempting to develop that uses location-awareness and geofencing. I was able to follow a tutorial explaining how to set up a geofence using hardcoded longitudes and latitudes.

Two questions:

First, is there any way to "push" new longitudes and latitudes from a server to the app and set them up as new geofence regions even when the app is closed (completely closed not in background)?

Second, is there a way to do this when the app is running in the background?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "First, is there any way to "push" new longitudes and latitudes from a
>   server to the app and set them up as new geofence regions even when
>   the app is closed"

You mean push new geofences to the app:
No, if the app is closed you cannot do that.

If the App wakes up it can request if there are any new geofences from the server.

Comment: Could I theoretically push a new geofence if the app is running in the background?

Comment: I dont know, please read the docu if push service is available in background, or ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should be able to add new geofences with the app running in the background, you just will need something that fires and event and use that call. For example you can use AlarmManager (alarms are lost if the device is turned off or restarted)

Hope this help, 
Hector

Answer (score 0):

The app can be waken up through a 'push notification' by the OS. Then as AlexWien states in his answer: "If the App wakes up it can request if there are any new geofences from the server.".